# 80-20 better than full dataset for LightGBM

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, error, validation

Recently I have been using LightGBM as regressor in order to predict, on a dataset of 20 thousand observations.

I have two modes, **1)** Production and **2)** Testing. The first one just trains a model with the whole dataset. The second does the same with an 80% of the dataset and tests over the remaining 20% (80-20 done with train_test_split, from sklearn.model_selection, no seed used).

In both cases I show the *neg_mean_squared_error* at the end of the execution. In the first case for the whole dataset, in the second I get two values (training and testing)

I am shocked to see that while in the first case my error is around -10, in the second the values are -5 (training) and -5.3 (testing). An average value of my objective variable can be 80. I would expect to lose accuracy since I train with less data and then I test over a different sample.

**Question**: There is any theoretical reason that explains that a 80-20 test gets a "better" neg_mean_squared_error than in the full data case? Or it has to be a (sneaky) bug in my code?

Comment: What happens when you take both models and predict on the exact same data?

Comment: Doesn't the first model 'overfit' because you train and test on the same (100%) of the data?  What happens if you use that model to predict on the same 20% testing data from the second model?  Is that value is lower than -5.3 (which ias you mention doesn't make intuitive sense)?